# Set custom shortcut to a menu item

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jrebel

Is there a way to know the shortcut key for a given menu item, or if not available set it, for example, set a shortcut to open the Maven panel on the right side of the IDE or open a custom run panel (e.g. JRebel executor)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign shortcuts for these actions in Settings | Keymap, under the "Tool Windows" group.